# How to send API call to a website in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to scan multiple URLs on Virustotal.com using APIs.

This is how Virustotal has defined how to send API requests.

curl --request POST 
url https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls 
header 'x-apikey: 'your API key' 
form url='url'

Please let me know how I can use this in a javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use XMLHttpRequest,it's a better than jQuery

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        for (let i in data) {


          console.log(data[i])
        }
    }
};
xhttp.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json")
xhttp.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "your API key")

xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: Getting CORS for this one as well

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,Content-Type,Accept

Answer (score -1):

You can use fetch() :  a web API that lets you make asynchronous requests.
It returns a “Promise” which is one of the great features of ES6. All though there are other ways too here : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/

```
const url= "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/urls";
    
      const otherParameters = {
          headers :{
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "x-api-key": "your API key"
          },
          method:"POST"
      }
    
      fetch(url,otherParameters)
      .then(data=>return data.json())
      .then(res=> console.log(res))
      .catch(error=> console.log(error));
```

Comment: Note this makes a big assumption that the API is CORS enabled. Many that require API keys are not so as to prevent exposing credentials in public

Comment: @charlietfl, It is not in my case, what are other options then?

Comment: @CapsLock Use your server as a proxy to do the remote request. Send data from client with ajax(fetch()) -> remote request-> return remote response to client ajax